# Google Indexed cgi-sys/default-webpage for mobile, but shows the site correctly in desktop search

Tags: google, https, google-index

I moved my page to HTTPS. In the search result from a PC, it is indexed correctly, but on mobile google indexed my webpage as `cgi-sys/defaultwebserver.php`.

To solve this problem I blocked `cgi-sys` from robots txt and sent a delete URL request to Google but now my website is completely deleted from mobile search results.

I can provide website URL if needed.

Comment: Your website URL would be helpful.    I've never seen Google do something like that before, being able to look at your website might help us figure it out.

Comment: Your title says `cgi-sys/default-webpage` but the body of the post says `cgi-sys/defaultwebserver.php`.  Which is it?